# Requests intercepted in Burp - Trustkit SSL pinning implemented

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have implemented SSL pinning in our mobile app using [Trustkit](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit-Android) for both platform iOS and Android.

Our application is built in React-Native and we followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jaedmuva/react-native-ssl-pinning-is-back-e317e6682642)

Let me describe what is happening on each platform

**Android:** 
My network security configuration looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.mydomain.com</domain>
        <pin-set>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">my_pin_1</pin>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">my_pin_2</pin>
        </pin-set>
        <trustkit-config enforcePinning="true">
        </trustkit-config>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I obtained my PKP Hash which used as pin(my_pin_1) from here https://report-uri.com/home/pkp_hash

Rest I have overwritten OkHttpClient to implement Trustkit as per getting started guide of Truskit-Android.

I have tested by setting wrong pins, in that case app stops working.

**iOS:**
Same way we have implemented Trustkit. In iOS logs it shows SSL pinning is implemented and working.

**Problem:**
Still our app's [network requests are getting intercepted](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit-Android/issues/38) in [Burp suite software](https://portswigger.net/burp). Which effectively fails the motive of SSL pinning.

Is there any work around to this?

Comment: Is that really your question, if someone else has faced the issue ? Please consider clarifying...

Comment: @2Dee Updated. Hope its clear now. If you still things there is something which not clear then let me know.